# Como posso fazer uma função para se o cliente clicar na imagen da coluna a esquerda ela abrir na div a direita?

Tags: html, css

Tenho que fazer o seguinte projeto da primeira imagem, vai mostrar uma coluna de propriedades(casas) e quando eu clicar em uma na direita vai mostrar a descrição da casa... se eu quiser ver mais detalhado clico em full info e a coluna que era só uma irá virar 2 e ao invés de mostrar as casas disponiveis irá mostrar as imagens da casa clicada...
Resolvi começar a fazer logo pela parte espandida(tela 2), na imagem 2 ja está o projeto mais ou menos, como posso fazer para quando o cliente clicar na foto da primeira coluna a mesma carregar na div com a imagem maior (coluna a direita)? E estou fazendo do modo certo? tem como fazer na mesma pagina isso do cliente clicar em full info e eu só fazer a coluna ficar maior? Desculpem o transtorno sou estagiario kkk, segue o código abaixo da imagem, tenho que fazer isso utilizando js?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#ofertas{
 float:left;
 height: 513px;
 background-color:  #EEE9E9;
 position: relative;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin-left: 3%;
 width: 36%;
}

#ofertas ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}



.margin-oferta{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width:163px;
 height: 169px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2% auto;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.margin-oferta h4{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.venda{
 position: relative;
 height: 150px;
 width: 163px;
 background: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0;

 
 }

.venda img{
 width: 163px;
 height: 150px;
}

.bar-right{
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 float: right;

}

.description{
 width: 87%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 1% auto 2%;
 background-color: #EEE9E9;

}

.margin-out{
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color: #EEE9E9;
 height: 420px;
 width: 700px;
}

#preco{

margin-left: 7%; 
margin-bottom: 0;"
}
.image-house{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 370px;
 width: 645px;
}

.image-house img{
 position: relative;
 margin: 3.5% auto;
 height: 370px;
 width: 645px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ofertas">
  <ul>
      <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 1</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 2</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 3</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 4</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 5</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 6</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 7</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 8</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="bar-right">
  <div class="margin-out">
   <div class="image-house">
    <img src="img/avatar4.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
  <p id="preco">£ 90 0000 </p>
  <div class="description">
   <p> This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome</p>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anderson, a sua pergunta está um pouco dificil de entender. Pelo que eu entendi, voce quer que a casa que voce clica em um menu apareça em tamanho maior do outro lado da tela, correto?

Bom, eu usei o jQuery para pegar o evento click da imagem, encontrar o src e atribuir a tag  maior. Além disso, o menu ira conter um campo label contendo os detalhes que voce quer exibir ao clicar no botao "Info"

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.venda').click(function(){
  $('.image-house img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));  
$('.description .p-description').text($(this).find('.label-description').text());

  });
  $('#btnInfo').click(function(){
  $('.description').show();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#ofertas{
 float:left;
 height: 513px;
 background-color:  #EEE9E9;
 position: relative;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin-left: 3%;
 width: 36%;
}

#ofertas ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}



.margin-oferta{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width:163px;
 height: 169px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 2% auto;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.margin-oferta h4{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.venda{
 position: relative;
 height: 150px;
 width: 163px;
 background: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0;

 
 }

.venda img{
 width: 163px;
 height: 150px;
}

.bar-right{
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0;
 width: 60%;
 height: auto;
 float: right;

}

.description{
 width: 87%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 1% auto 2%;
 background-color: #EEE9E9;
  display:none;

}

.label-description{
display:none;
}

.p-description{
}

.margin-out{
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color: #EEE9E9;
 height: 420px;
 width: 700px;
}

#preco{

margin-left: 7%; 
margin-bottom: 0;"
}
.image-house{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 370px;
 width: 645px;
}

.image-house img{
 position: relative;
 margin: 3.5% auto;
 height: 370px;
 width: 645px;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.venda img').click(function(){
$('.image-house img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ofertas">
  <ul>
      <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 1</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="http://blog.eucontrato.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ideia-casa-reforma-fachada-construcao-telhado-platibanda.jpg">
          <label class="label-description">esse texto é o detalhe da casa 1</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 2</h4>
    <div class="venda">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ22cCH-q_nwhbc5CiTPjgQpzoDfxQP7lKnUE_OhoFQG5WzKXrf">
             <label class="label-description">esse texto é o detalhe da casa 2</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 3</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
           <label class="label-description">esse texto é o detalhe da casa 3</label>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 4</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 5</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 6</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 7</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="margin-oferta">
       <h4>Casa 8</h4>
    <div class="venda">
     <img src="img/2.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="bar-right">
  <div class="margin-out">
   <div class="image-house">
    <img src="img/avatar4.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
    <input id="btnInfo" type="button" value="info"/>
  <p id="preco">£ 90 0000 </p>
  <div class="description">
   <p class="p-description"> This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome<br>
    This house is recommended for those who have a big family. it's very big and handsome</p>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo muito Obrigado !